# Unable to configure Gitlab Agent for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have Gitlab Kubernetes integration in my `Project 1` and I am able to access the `kube-context` within that project's pipelines without any issues.

I have another project, `Project 2` where I want to use the same cluster that I integrated in my `Project 1`.

This i my agent config file:

```
# .gitlab/agents/my-agent/config.yaml

ci_access:
  projects:
    - id: group/project-2
```

When I try to add a Kubernetes cluster in my `Project 2`, I am expecting to see the cluster name that I set up for `Project 1` in the dropdown, but I don't see it:

[image: gitlab-agent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ensured that the agent configuration file `config.yaml` is present in your `project2` at the specified directory?

If you have, you should be able to choose the agent from the list and setup Gitlab with it. Having the configuration file in both projects is [necessary](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/#create-an-agent-configuration-file) when you configure multiple projects to use the same k8s cluster.

Comment: that's what the problem was. could you please confirm what needs to be the `id` for `Project 1` and what needs to be the id for `Project 2` ? So far I'm using `group/project-2` as `id` for both. Thanks.

Comment: So I did manage to see the cluster name in the dropdown of `Project 2` but I am unable to get it connected. I ran the `helm upgrade --install` commands it gives to be run in the cluster but it still says `Never connected`

Comment: Don't you need to setup the gitlab agent on the group instead of the project? That way you automatically have kubernetes integration on all projects inside that group

Comment: Did you go through step 2 described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/index.html#install-the-agent-with-helm) in the docs? It tells how to `connect` with your cluster for running helm.

Answer (score 1):

[GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#share-cicd-access-to-the-agent-within-a-personal-namespace) (December 2022) suggests an alternative approach, which does not involve creating a new agent per project

> ### Share CI/CD access to the agent within a personal namespace
>
> The GitLab agent for Kubernetes provides a more secure solution for managing your clusters with GitLab CI/CD.
> You can use a single agent with multiple projects and groups by sharing access
> to the agent connection. In previous releases, you could not share access with personal
> namespaces. This release adds support for CI/CD connection sharing to personal namespaces.
> You can now use a single agent from any of the projects under your personal namespace.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_7/configure-allow-agent-cicd-access-sharing-within-a-personal-namesp.png -- Share CI/CD access to the agent within a personal namespace]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_workflow.html#authorize-the-agent) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/356831).

That means from a single agent, you should be able to access an agent connection from multiple projects (personal namespace or not).

Answer (score 0):

So I've been facing the same problem at the company I'm working on due to the supposed deprecation of certificate-based Kubernetes integration in November 2022 that just got delayed to February 2023.

As far as I could gather, the agent only appears in the registered agents list of the configuration project, but to the authorized projects or groups, it works as advertised.

I would recommend setting up a group variable that holds the respective `<group/subgroup:agent_name>` value so that you can reference it throughout the `.gitlab-ci.yml` files of the projects of the group.

zer0's proposed solution is missleading as it makes you create a new agent per project and can cause an overload of agents in your cluster.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).